# Implementing the 'cat' command

Tags: c, unix

The options for the 'cat' command are as follows:

> ```
>  -b      Number the non-blank output lines, starting at 1.
>
>  -e      Display non-printing characters (see the -v option), and display
>          a dollar sign (`$') at the end of each line.
>
>  -n      Number the output lines, starting at 1.
>
>  -s      Squeeze multiple adjacent empty lines, causing the output to be
>          single spaced.
>
>  -t      Display non-printing characters (see the -v option), and display
>          tab characters as `^I'.
>
>  -u      Disable output buffering.
>
>  -v      Display non-printing characters so they are visible.  Control
>          characters print as `^X' for control-X; the delete character
>          (octal 0177) prints as `^?'.  Non-ASCII characters (with the high
>          bit set) are printed as `M-' (for meta) followed by the character
>          for the low 7 bits.
> ```

---

```c
#include 'stdlib.h'
#include 'stdio.h'
#include 'string.h'
#include 'unistd.h'
#define len 256;

/*function declarations*/

void non_blank (FILE *fin, FILE *fout, int writeLineNumbers);
void dollar_sign(FILE *fin, FILE *fout, int writeLineNumbers);  //test comment   
void output_line(FILE *fin, FILE *fout, int writeLineNumbers);
void squeeze (FILE *fin, FILE *fout, int writeLineNumbers);
void non_printing (FILE *fin, FILE *fout, int writeLineNumbers);
void non_printingvisible ((FILE *fin, FILE *fout, int writeLineNumbers);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int opt=0;
int bflag = 0;
int eflag = 0;
int nflag = 0;
int sflag = 0;
int tflag = 0;
int vflag = 0;


//Not sure what value is stored in opt?

while((opt=getopt(argc, argv, "benstv"))!=-1)
switch (opt)
{
    case 'b':
        bflag=1;
        non_blank(stdin, stdout, opt);
        break;
    case 'e':
        eflag=1;
        dollar_sign(stdin, stdout, opt);
        break;
    case 'n':  //test comment   
        nflag=1;
        output_line(stdin, stdout, opt);
        break;
    case 's':
        sflag=1;
        squeeze(stdin, stdout, opt);
        break;
    case 't':
        tflag=1;
        non_printing(stdin, stdout, opt);
        break;
    case 'v':
        vflag=1;
        non_printingvisible(stdin, stdout, opt);
        break;
    default:
        abort();
}
       //test comment   

//implementing -b functionality 
void non_blank (FILE *fin, FILE *fout, int writeLineNumbers)
{
    char line[len];
    int linenumber=1;

    while (fgets(line,len,fin))
    {
        if(writeLineNumbers)
        printf("%d",linenumber);
        if (fputs(line, fout)==EOF)
        {  //test comment   
            printf(stderr,"Write to stdout failed.");
            return;
        }
        if(line[0]!='\0')
        ++linenumber;
    }
}

// implementing -e functionality.                          
void dollar_sign (FILE *fin, FILE *fout, int writeLineNumbers)
{
    char line[len];
    int linenumber=1;

    while (fgets(line,len,fin))  //test comment   
    {
        if(writeLineNumbers)
        printf("  $");
        if (fputs(line, fout)==EOF)
        {
            printf(stderr,"Write to stdout failed.");
            return;
        }
        ++linenumber;
    }
}

//implementing -n functionality                            
void output_line (FILE *fin, FILE *fout, int writeLineNumbers)
{
    char line[len];
    int linenumber=1;
      //test comment   
    while (fgets(line,len,fin))
    {
        if(writeLineNumbers)
            printf("%d",linenumber);
        if (fputs(line, fout)==EOF)
        {
            printf(stderr,"Write to stdout failed.");
            return;
        }
        ++linenumber;
    }
}

/*     void output_line (FILE *fin, FILE *fout, int writeLineNumbers)
{
    char line[len];
    int linenumber=1;  //test comment   

    while (fgets(line,len,fin))
    {
        if(writeLineNumbers)
        printf("%d",linenumber);
        if (fputs(line, fout)==EOF)
        {
            printf(stderr,"Write to stdout failed.");
            return;
        }
        ++linenumber;
    }
}
          */

//implementing -s functionality            

void squeeze ( FILE *fin, FILE *fout, int writeLineNumbers)
{
    char line[len] = {0};
   // int linenumber=1;
      //test comment   
    while (fgets(line,len,fin))
    {
        if(line[0]=='\n')
            fin--=fin;
        else if (fputs(line, fout)==EOF)
        {
            printf(stderr,"Write to stdout failed.");
            return;
        }
      //  ++linenumber;
    }
}                              
  //test comment   
/*should converting each char to int  (for ASCII value) and then printing back in char                     fix it? */

void non_printing ( FILE *fin, FILE *fout, int writeLineNumbers)
{
   char line[len];
   int linenumber= 1;
   int i;

   while (fgets(line,len,fin))
    {
       i=strlen(line);  //test comment   
       for(i=0;i<strlen;i++)  //test comment   
       line[i]

//test comment         
      if(line==NULL)
          fin--;
      if (fputs(line, fout)==EOF)
      {
          printf(stderr,"Write to stdout failed.");
          return;
      }
      ++linenumber;
 }
}
```

Comment: You seem to be missing some code in `main()`, as well as a level of indentation.

Answer (score 4):

You're initializing but not using local variables like `bflag`.

Is the user allowed to specify more than one option? [Source code for GNU's cat found here](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=coreutils.git;a=blob_plain;f=src/cat.c;hb=HEAD) says "Yes, multiple options can be specified". So instead of calling a different routine for each option, you should call the same routine for all options, and apply any/all specified options for each line read.

You're always reading from `stdin` however `cat` allows the input filename to be specified on the command-line.

Your version assumes that 256 is the maximum length of line in the input file.

You're passing `writeLineNumbers` as a parameter to all subroutines but not using it in most of the subroutines.